# HQL to tell if a value is in a joined table

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have 2 Entity tables (Scenario and Tag) and a join table representing a many to many relationship. Using Scenario as a base table, I have created a sql statement that allows me to see if a tag is part of the set of tags associated with a single scenario and output all scenarios that have that tag:

```
select count(*)
from scenarios
where scenarios.id not in (
    select tag_to_scenarios.scenarioid
    from tag_to_scenarios
    join tags ON tags.id = tag_to_scenarios.tagid
    where (
        exists( 
            select concat(group_concat(tags.tagname), ',') as tag_list
            from scenarios as sub_scenarios
            left outer join tag_to_scenarios ON tag_to_scenarios.scenarioid = sub_scenarios.id
            join tags ON tags.id = tag_to_scenarios.tagid
            where scenarios.id = sub_scenarios.id
            group by scenarios.id
            having (position('@regression,' in tag_list) = 0))
        )
    )
 );
```

Here are the relevant parts of the model being used:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@NotNull
@Column(name = "tagname")
private String tagName;

public void setTagName(String tagName) {
    this.tagName = tagName;
}

public String getTagName() {
    return tagName;
}

}

@Entity
```

@Table(name="scenarios")
public class Scenario {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "tag_to_scenarios",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "scenarioid", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tagid", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "scenarioid", columnNames = {"tagid"})
)
private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<Tag>(0);

public Set<Tag>  getTags() {
    return this.tags;
}

public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
}
```

I need to transform this SQL statement into HQL since I don't have the join table in my model.

Answer (score 3):

The following HQL can help you accomplish this:

```
  SELECT s from Scenario s
    JOIN s.tags t 
   WHERE t.name = :tag 
GROUP BY s 
  HAVING count(t) = 1
```

Credits are from the following site:

http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-write-many-to-many-search-queries-in-mysql-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I didn't understand your SQL query but if all you want to do is get the scenarios that have a given flag then the following HQL query should be enough :

```
SELECT s.id FROM Scenario s JOIN tags t WHERE t.tagName = :tagName
```